# Conditional Selection in Google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Hey Guys so im trying to make some conditional statements in google forms using google app scripts.
For example lets say I have a drop-down question in google forms that asks "Are you a vegetarian"?
and the drop-down is "Yes or No". Then I want the next dropdown to show a dropdown based on if the person picks yes or no. If they pick yes, I want a dropdown list of vegetables, and if they pick no I want a dropdown list of meaty foods.

Is that possible in google forms using google app scripts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that in the current stage, your goal cannot be achieved using Google Form. I apologize for this. As another method, how about using the custom form created by HTML and Google Apps Script?

Comment: Thank you for your response, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill.  In the current stage, Google Forms cannot be dynamically changed using a script. So as the current answer, the answer to your question of `Is that possible in google forms using google app scripts?` is that unfortunately, your goal cannot be achieved using Google Form. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: Ohh I understand you clearly but you mentioned "using the custom form created by HTML and Google Apps Script?", how would I go about that?

Comment: By using html, client side javascript and google apps script then you can gain the ability to interact with the user filling out the form as you might with a website.  The down side is that it requires more knowledge and experience to achieve this result

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I noticed that I misunderstood your replying. And also, I noticed that a comment has already been posted for your question.